# Sending/handling GET requests in typescript using Express, Request and Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, npm-request

I'm using a combination of Express and Request (installed using npm) to try to send a get request to get some json from the server. However no matter what I do the body that is returned is "undefined".

This is the code in my server.js file. The json isn't actually what I'm sending, it's just an example as I can't post what I'm actually sending.

```
import express = require("express");
import bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/config', function(req, res){
    res.json('{name: test}');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

I've tried both of the following but both of them say that body is undefined.

```
import request = require("request");

let req = {
    url: `http://localhost:3000/config`,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

request(req, function(error, response, body){
    this.config = JSON.parse(body);
})

request(`/config`, function(err, res, body) {
    this.config = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've never used express or request before so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

If I change the request code to the following, the inside of the function is never run. Does anyone know why this would be?

```
let req = {
    url: `http://localhost:3000/config`,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

request(req, function(error, response, body){
    console.log("response => "+JSON.parse(body));
    return JSON.parse(body);
})
```

Comment: I copy pasted your 1st example code and I got back '{name: test}' using `postman`. Is that the output you are expecting?

Comment: Yes that's what I want. I guess it must be something wrong with my Request stuff then.

Comment: Not sure about it. I was just doing a simple "GET" . Empty header. Maybe worth having a look at the tools or API that you are using to make the call, maybe it is adding some pepper and salt to the raw response. I would also check the HTTP response code and make sure it is not getting 404.

Comment: In the client code - your url should be `localhost:3000/config`.

Comment: When I do it in postman it says "Cannot GET/config". How did you get the response back?

Answer (score 2):

Since OP hasn't got it working and I believe the code he got up there is correct. I may as well post my working solution here to help him get started.

Hopefully this will save you hours of debugging...

**Client:**

```
"use strict";
let request = require("request");

let req = {
    url: `localhost:4444/config`,
    proxy: 'http://localhost:4444',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

request(req, function (err, res, body) {
    this.config = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("response => " + this.config);
});
```

**Server:**

```
"use strict";
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var config = require('config');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/config', function(req, res){
    res.json('{name: test}');
});

// Start the server
app.set('port', 4444);

app.listen(app.get('port'), "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log('started');
});
```

**Output:**

> response => {name: test}

Comment: @annedroiid Let me know if this works for you. Note I'm using a different port here. `4444`

Comment: When I put that in I get "Error: Invalid protocol: localhost:"

Comment: @annedroiid cant replicate it... I will remove that proxy line and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know if you have posted whole of your server's code, it seems like you missed `app.listen(port)` so that your server cannot be started up correctly.

Also, if you added `if (error) { console.log(error); }` at the first line of the callback function of `request`, you'll find it print an error: `[Error: Invalid URI "/config"]`

And that's why the `body` is always `undefined`: You have to give the full url such like `http://localhost:xxxx` to `request`.

In short:

- Your server didn't listen to a specific port. `app.listen(5678)`
- Your client didn't know the complete url. `request('http://localhost:5678/config', (...)=>{...})`

Comment: It's set to automatically use localhost. I also do have app.listen(3000) to the port, I just forgot to include it my comment.

Comment: automatically use localhost? Do you mean your client request? It won't, imho. And you didn't tell the client which port should it send the request to. Just print a log about the error, and you'll get the reason why it didn't work. Error message could always be very useful.